# Customized ListView when scrolling changes randomly button text or edittext

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have searched for this one but to no avail I haven't get the exact answer to the issue.

I have a button inside a `ListView`, when that button is clicked it shows an alert dialog to choose a date and after choosing date, the selected date will be the text of the button. The code works fine but when i scroll down and up the date will be randomly change 
here is my code for the `getView()` method of my adapter.**This also happens to the `EditText` when i type to any of the `EditText` works fine but when i start scrolling the values also change.**

Here is my get view method

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.repeat_entry_listview,null);

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.btnDate = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rpbtnDate);
        viewHolder.txtNotes  = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rpNotes);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }else{
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }


    RepeatEntryList repeatEntryList = listData.get(position);
    viewHolder.btnDate.setText(repeatEntryList.getDate());
    viewHolder.btnDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          //EVEN IF I REMOVE THE CODE FOR SETTING THE BUTTON TEXT TO JUST LIKE THE BELOW CODE. SCROLLING ISSUES STILL PERSIST

          viewHolder.btnDate.setText("just sample date text");

            //**NOTE UPDATED**
            //MY EDITTEXT ALSO HAVE THE SAME BEHAVIOR
        }
    });
    viewHolder.txtNotes.setHint(contx.getResources().getString(R.string.placeholder_txt));
    return convertView;
}
```

**Note** Let's say i have 20 buttons and 20 `EditText` inside the `ListView`. When i type something to all of the `EditText` and change the text of the button by clicking it ,then scroll down and up the `ListView` ,the text or values of `EditText` and button will change or interchange and sometimes gone.

With regards to my problem can someone explain to me why `ListView` is behaving like this and how to avoid this certain behavior.

Comment: @Shoeb Siddique im sorry to say but you answer does not help me sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what i have done to solve my problem is incase someone might have the same problem:
 1. First i create i variable inside my custom Adapter class which is RepeatEntryListAdapter and called it listData

```
public ArrayList<RepeatEntryList> listData;
```

2. i reference listData variable to be the array list of RepeatEntryList class which is my getter and setter class like this.

```
public RepeatEntryListAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<RepeatEntryList> listdata){
          this.listData = listdata;
            this.contx = context;
            mainActivity = (MainActivity) context;
            layoutInflater= LayoutInflater.from(context);
       }
```

3. Inside getview method i created click event for the button .Inside the click event I instantiated my getter class then use the instantiated variable of my getter class and use settext,for setting the text of the button and also set the date for the **lisData** variable.and the important part is use the **listData** variable in which i use the position variable to set the value of a certain position of the **listData** varaible like this.

```
 RepeatEntryList re = rListData;
 viewHolder.btnDate.setText('07-06-2015')//say the date selected is the string inside setText                          re.setDate(viewHolder.btnDate.getText().toString());//set Date is a setter method inside my RepeatEntryList class
 listData.set(position, re);//position variable should be final
```

4. This is the most trickiest part which is part in solving the scrolling problem of my custom list view which is caused by the edittext watcher which **fires when scrolling** . what i did is.

a. i Created a class that implements TextWatcher like this

```
class EditTextWatcher implements TextWatcher{

        private int mPosition;
        private boolean mActive;

        void setPosition(int position){
            mPosition = position;
        }
        void setActive(boolean active){
            mActive = active;
        }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(mActive){
                //rNotes.set(mPosition,s.toString());
                RepeatEntryList re = listData.get(mPosition);
                re.setNotes(s.toString());
                listData.set(mPosition,re);
            }
        }
    }
```

b. i also created a variable for EditeTextWatcher inside my static class ViewHolder

```
 static class ViewHolder{
   public Button btnDate;
   public EditText txtNotes;
   public EditTextWatcher mWatcher;
}
```

c. inside my getview method ,i created a new instance of EditTextWatcher() which also create a new textwatcher and not use the last event because i create a new instance of the textwatcher

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder viewHolder;

        final RepeatEntryList rListData = listData.get(position);

        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.repeat_entry_listview,null);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.btnDate = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rpbtnDate);
            viewHolder.mWatcher = new EditTextWatcher();
            viewHolder.txtNotes  = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rpNotes);
            viewHolder.txtNotes.addTextChangedListener(viewHolder.mWatcher);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }else{
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();


        }

        viewHolder.btnDate.setText(rListData.getDate());

        viewHolder.mWatcher.setActive(false);
        viewHolder.txtNotes.setText(rListData.getNotes());
        viewHolder.mWatcher.setPosition(position);
        viewHolder.mWatcher.setActive(true);


      //here is the part of button click event i mention above (no 3.)
return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

make changes in your code remove if(convertView == null){ }else{} condition and directly use as follow

```
convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.repeat_entry_listview,null);
Button btnDate = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rpbtnDate);
TextView txtNotes  = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rpNotes);
```

Comment: I have tried i a while ago and the problem still persist

Comment: @jameshwart lopez Try to remove view holder and bind controls directly.

Comment: sir i dont get your idea sir.

Comment: its not really solving my problem sir

Answer (score 3):

Make your `position` variable `final` in `getView`

```
final int position
```

And also make your modal class as Final.

```
final RepeatEntryList repeatEntryList = listData.get(position);
```

Comment: yes sir for final int position but for final RepeatEntryList is not a modal its a class

Comment: its a getter setter class, so make it final

Comment: You need to create a String variable in RepeatEntryList with getter setters and set the date on setter and then get the date via getter and show it to your btn text.

Comment: sir i just made it final.. but my problem is not solve :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82784/discussion-between-shoeb-siddique-and-jameshwart-lopez).

Answer (score 3):

Just add below line, repeatEntryList.setDate("Selected Date")

```
datePickerTo.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                String strdate = (pickerTo.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + pickerTo.getDayOfMonth() + "-" + pickerTo.getYear();

                                viewHolder.btnDate.setText(mainActivity.pickerStringTodate(strdate));

//Here is your new line
repeatEntryList.setDate(mainActivity.pickerStringTodate(strdate))


                                try {
                                    Date date1 = mainActivity.dateFormat.parse(viewHolder.btnDate.getText().toString());
                                    Date date2 = mainActivity.dateFormat.parse(mainActivity.dateFormat.format(new Date()));
                                    if (date1.before(date2)) {
                                        Toast.makeText(contx, "You cannot select past date", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        viewHolder.btnDate.setText(mainActivity.dateFormat.format(new Date()));
                                    }
                                } catch (ParseException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
                        datePickerTo.show();
```

Comment: can i ask what's the logic behind your answer?

Comment: @jameshwartlopez ListView have behavior of recycle the views, while you scroll down or scroll up, the view get recycle.  that's why we need to maintain state of each view. consider your example , Bean class uses to maintain the state.  on the selection of single view date you need to save that in somewhere that is your bean class. and once you save date for that view you need to write a code to set view value from that bean class. Don't forget to call notifydatasetchange() on your adapter. because when list data change you need to call this one.

Comment: but with regards to the edittext im trying to implement thesame idea

Answer (score 2):

You are using an if condition:

```
if (date1.before(date2)) { 
    Toast.makeText(contx, "You cannot select past date", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    viewHolder.btnDate.setText(mainActivity.dateFormat.format(new Date()));
}else{viewHolder.btnDate.setVisibility(View.GONE);}
```

But there is no else case. The else case should be handled too.

Comment: sir eventhough i remove all the code inside onClick method and just replace it with  viewHolder.btnDate.setText("just sample date text"); the behavior after scrolling still persist

Comment: just try with out if. does any problem you have

Comment: yes the button text will disappear if i scroll.. (say 20 edit text inside the listview)  when i typed and all of it and scroll text will appear and disappear or the value will transfer to other text

Comment: Try this      if (date1.before(date2)) { 
    Toast.makeText(contx, "You cannot select past date", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    viewHolder.btnDate.setText(mainActivity.dateFormat.format(new Date()));
}else{ viewHolder.btnDate.setVisibility(View.GONE);}

Comment: sir i updated my question please read especially the code part